# Method to read/write to excel file from a Domino schedule agent

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Have requirement to read/write to excel file from Domino server agent. What's the good method ? Excel is NOT install on the server, so I was thinking of using the Apache POI. Maybe with an xAgent if I can call that from schedule agent.

Thanks
Bob

Comment: Easiest way is to copy the Apache POI JAR files to the servers jvm/lib/ext folder. Then write a Java agent that creates the Excel file. See here for an example: https://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-write-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi

Comment: Thanks Mark,  However I must be doing something wrong,  In the Notes designer I'm unable to import the apache POI .  I did put the jar file into the jvm/iib/ext on my workstation and on the server.

Comment: on my workstation there a folder jvm1.6/lib/ext Once I put the jar file in there everything worked.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it. You're on that fix pack version that supports 2 java versions. Didn't think about that...